# Windows 8 App - Binding GridView to XML

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm working on my first Windows 8 app. I'm trying to display a GridView populated with TextBlock's. I want to get my data from an XML file I created. I found the ItemSource property of the GridView and want to bind my XML file to it. But, my XML file isn't showing up in the local resources menu.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Why not deserialize first the xml into a custom object or a List of strings, and then bind it to the ItemsSource?

Comment: @margabit I could do that, is that the preferred method?

Comment: There are some ways to do it. You could use a XMLDataProvider too. Maybe is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XmlDataProvider to bind a XML directly into the controls. Find an example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26875/WPF-XmlDataProvider-Two-Way-Data-Binding

I'm not sure though if you can use it in WinRT. If you do not, you can deserialize the XML into a List and bind it to the ItemsSource of the GridView.

Comment: Seems like XmlDataProvider isn't supported on WinRT (or at least with Windows Store apps). I'll try deserializing it into a list. Thanks.